# How to send email from form using Nodemailer

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, email, nodemailer

Let's start off by saying I am a beginner at node and javascript. I have a website that I built using HTML, CSS, and ASP.NET. There is an email form setup on my website that i wanted to convert from ASP.NET to Node.js simply for the learning experience. I have followed several different tutorials to attempting to get this piece to work. I keep coming up short!

I have successfully made my html email form accept data and the node picks it up. However attempting to grab the node and send it in the form of an email using nodemailer, not so much. I notice several tutorials use "routes" I would like to avoid this option because it simply goes over my head. If someone could explain how to do that or why not to do that or how it cant be done? I would be appreciative. Here's my code that i have so far:

Javascript/Node:

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.post('/contact', function(req, res) {
    var mailOpts, smtpConfig;
    //Setup Nodemailer transport, I chose gmail. Create an application-specific             password to avoid problems.
    smtpConfig = nodemailer.createTransport('SMTP', {
        service: 'Gmail',
        auth: {
            user: "<myUser>",
            pass: "<myPassword>"
        }
    });
    //Mail options
    mailOpts = {
        from: req.query.name + ' &lt;' + req.query.email + '&gt;',
        //grab form    data from the request body object
        to: '<other user>',
        subject: 'Website contact form',
        text: req.query.message
    };
    smtpConfig.sendMail(mailOpts, function(error, response) {
        //Email not sent
        if (error) {
            res.end("Email send failed");
            //res.render('contact', { title: 'Raging Flame Laboratory - Contact',   msg: 'Error occured, message not sent.', err: true, page: 'contact' })
            //console.log("error");
        }//Yay!! Email sent
        else {
            res.end("Email send successfully");
            //res.render('contact', { title: 'Raging Flame Laboratory - Contact',  msg: 'Message sent! Thank you.', err: false, page: 'contact' })
            //console.log("success");
        }
    });
});

app.listen(8081, function() {
    console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8081/');
});
```

HTML:

```
<form action="http://127.0.0.1:8087/contact" method="post">
    <b>send us a quote</b>
    </br>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="Name">
    </br>
    <!--input type="text" name="bname" id="bname" value="Business Name"></br>-->
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="Email Address">
    </br>
    <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="10">Enter detailed information here</textarea>
    </br>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="send message">
</form>
```

Comment: Anyone got anything?

Comment: Here is a comple and working code: https://www.noodl.io/market/product/P201601221424994/email-composer-send-emails-with-nodejs-and-mailgun

Answer (score 1):

You have a mistake on your requests. There shoud by req.body instead of req.query

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

after

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Mike

Answer (score 0):

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

// Create a SMTP transport object
var transport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP", {
    service: 'Hotmail',
    auth: {
        user: "username",
        pass: "password"
    }
  });

console.log('SMTP Configured');

// Message object
 var message = {

// sender info
from: from,

// Comma separated list of recipients
to: req.query.to ,

// Subject of the message
subject:req.query.subject //'Nodemailer is unicode friendly ✔', 

// plaintext body
text: req.query.text //'Hello to myself!',

// HTML body
 /*  html:'<p><b>Hello</b> to myself <img src="cid:note@node"/></p>'+
     '<p>Here\'s a nyan cat for you as an embedded attachment:<br/></p>'*/
};

console.log('Sending Mail');
transport.sendMail(message, function(error){
if(error){
  console.log('Error occured');
  console.log(error.message);
  return;
}
 console.log('Message sent successfully!');

 // if you don't want to use this transport object anymore,uncomment    
 //transport.close(); // close the connection pool
});
```